# sphinx fulltext searching with column filtering

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing, sphinx

I am trying to search columns "pagetitle" OR "content" for search term "phrase" AND 
WHERE column "class_key" === "modDocument".

Nothing is being returned currently

PHP

```
$sphinx = new SphinxClient();
$sphinx->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$query = $sphinx->Query('"phrase" @class_key modDocument', 'myIndex');
```

If I take "@class_key modDocument" out of the query I get results

sphinx.conf

```
source myIndex : src {

    sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM tx3nh_site_content
    sql_query = SELECT id, pagetitle, content FROM tx3nh_site_content WHERE id>=$start AND id<=$end

}

index myIndex {

    source = myIndex
    path = /home/sphinx/data/myIndex
    min_word_len = 3
    min_infix_len = 3

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sql_query = SELECT id, pagetitle, content FROM ...
```

There is no column called `class_key` listed!

You need to add the column to the `sql_query`, so that sphinx gets the data to be able include it in the index!